# IBAction Subview with Storyboard

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to add a subview using storyboard. It's being displayed correctly, but there's no button (`IBAction`) in subview that works correctly, even with empty code, the app always crashes when clicked.

TableViewController.m

```
...
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Load SubView    
    SubviewViewController *subview = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SubviewViewController"];
    [self.view addSubview:subview.view];
}
...
```

SubviewViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)btnCloseSubview:(id)sender
{
    // Crashes the app when clicked, even empty as it's. 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't just add another view controller's view to your view like that, it can get you into trouble. When I've tried that, it sometimes works and sometimes not. The proper way is to also add the controller as a child view controller of TableViewController:

```
SubviewViewController *subview = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SubviewViewController"];
[self addChildViewController: subview];
[subview didMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self.view addSubview:subview.view];
```

You probably need to set the frame of subview's view as well (subview.view.frame = self.view.bounds if you want it to be the same size).

As an alternative, you could create a view, not a view controller, in a xib file, and add that as a subview of your view. In that case, you would set the file's owner of the xib to TableViewController, and put the button's method in TableViewController.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my code now is working properly! I would like to ask if this solution is completely correct or if theres a better way to do that.

Comment: @LucianoNascimento, this is the correct way to add a child view controller in code. You didn't say what you're trying to accomplish though, so whether this is the best way to reach your goal, I don't know. You could add just a view as I said, or you could present the SubviewViewController as a modal controller -- it all depends on your purpose.

Comment: @Luciano Nascimento: If your problem is solved, I suggest that you accept the answer by checking the checkmark.

Answer (score 2):

Look into UIContainerView, it handles sub-view controllers.  You will need to handle your own communication between parent and child view controllers, but other than that it will work like you need it to for a sub-view, as long as your sub-view has the proper outlets and actions set up in the storyboard with it's view controller.

Have a look for more [in-depth information](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html) on container views.

Comment: +1 for the documentation reference. It has cleared all the ambiguity in my mind

Comment: "You will need to handle your own communication between parent and child view controllers". Can you tell me how? I'm having the following problem... :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32361624/gesture-recognizer-and-ibaction-in-a-uiviewcontroller-child-embedded-in-anothe. Thank you anyway